# ¿Cómo puedo quitar el color de líneas en VSCODE? (focus)

Tags: vscode

Instalé la extención Dobri Next en Code, y al elegir el tema Black, las líneas donde se encuentra el cursor están coloreadas con un color azul estresante.
¿Cómo lo puedo quitar? (Línea 5)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el sitio web del plugin parece que está la documentación para customizar el theme: https://github.com/dobbbri/bunker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Gracias Camilo, ya la vi, pero no encuentro lo que busco :l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente para resolverlo:

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Render Line Highlight: "none"
```

Comment: Gracias @NameNotFound